# How to find the array length depending on the status of an obj flag

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of todos and I am trying to show the num of completed an incompleted todos. I know that I can do `array.length` and I can find the total num but in this case I am stack.

```
this.state = {
  text: '',
  notes: [
     {todo: "hello", completed: true},
     {todo: "world", completed: false}
  ]
}
```

All (notes.length) 2   Completed (?) 0   Incompleted (?) 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `filter`

```
let completedCount = this.state.notes.filter(n => n.completed).length;
let incompleteCount = this.state.notes.length - completedCount;
```

or use `reduce`

```
let result = this.state.notes.reduce( (acc, curr) => {
   if(curr.completed) acc.complete++;
   else acc.incomplete++;
   return acc;
}, {complete:0,incomplete:0});
console.log(result.complete); // 1
console.log(result.incomplete); // 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter()` to reduce records in the object array and can find the length of the records present, it behaves similarly as `where` in SQL query. You can add a condition to any *key* present in the array.

```
completed = state.notes.filter(x=>x.Completed==true).length;
incomplete = state.notes.filter(x=>x.Completed==false).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the completed notes, and then check length:

```
const completedNotes = notes.filter((note) => note.completed)


completedNotes.length
```

Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

One can achieve this using reduce.

```
var a = {
  text: '',
  notes: [
     {todo: "hello", completed: true},
     {todo: "world", completed: false},
     {todo: "hello", completed: true},
     {todo: "world", completed: false},
     {todo: "hello", completed: true},
     {todo: "world", completed: false},
     {todo: "hello", completed: true},
     {todo: "world", completed: true}
  ]
};


let count = a.notes.reduce((b,n)=>{
  if (n.completed)
      b.x.push(n);
  else
      b.y.push(n)
  return b;
}, {x:[], y:[]});

console.log(count.x.length + ' ' + count.y.length);
```

Iterate through the notes array using reduce, pass an empty object as a parameter for reduce (this object should contain completed and incompleted as keys) return new object from reduce and apply the length property on that array, you will get the length of both.

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/jokayuxuvo/edit?js,console